# Using grep to extract IP through adb shell

Tags: shell, grep, regular-expression, ip, adb

I'm trying to create a one-line, platform-independent solution for finding the local IP address of a Android device with `adb shell` and `grep` (the internal grep on my android device). I have a solution that works, but something keeps bothering me.

By the way, I'm running my solution from within Powershell 7, if that makes any difference.

Here's my solution:

```
> adb shell "ip addr show wlan0 | grep -e 'inet[^6]'"
    inet 192.168.0.19/22 brd 192.168.3.255 scope global wlan0
```

It works, but I cannot use `\d` as a character class to filter, which would be preferable.

My preferred solution would show JUST the IP address and nothing else. This is the best I could do:

```
> adb shell "ip addr show wlan0 | grep -o '^    inet [0-9][0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9][0-9].[0-9]'"
    inet 192.168.0
```

Android seems to ship with a limited terminal setting and uses 'toybox' to emulate the typical bash tools. They seem quite limited though, and not very much documentation is provided.

Since I can't use digit character classes or quantifiers, I can only filter for the line, and using `-o` is the only way to output information. So, my preferred solution is effectively impossible to do.

What can I do to extract just my local IP address with this limited toolset?

Comment: Just throwing a stone here: why can't you use the `\d`? Could you try to escape the *\\* using `\\d`?

Comment: I tried that and many variations. Escaping with double `\`, using Powershell's escaping method, variations of quotes etc. and I couldn't find one that let me use standard character classes.

Answer (score 1):

You could just run the `grep` locally rather than as part of your `adb` expression:

```
$ adb shell "ip addr show wlan0" | 
  grep -o -P  '^ *inet \d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}'
inet 192.168.1.167
```

The `-P` option there means `--perl-regexp`, and is necessary to support the `\d` escape.

You could also just use a combination of `awk` and `cut`:

```
$ adb shell "ip addr show wlan0 | awk '\$1 == \"inet\" {print \$2}' | cut -f1 -d/"
192.168.1.167
```

There's a bunch of escaping there to prevent the local shell from expanding things like `$1` locally.

---

Or heck, forget traditional tools like `grep` and `awk` and do it using JSON and `jq`:

```
$ adb shell "ip -j addr show wlan0"  | jq -r '.[]|select(.ifname).addr_info[]|select(.family=="inet").local'
192.168.1.167
```